# Django: Custom router for read-replica raises OperationalError on save (with related models)

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I'm testing out a custom database router for a Django project to support read replicas (based on the [Django docs on multiple database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/multi-db/)) and **when I create model instances containing references to other models, the `save` method tries to use the read-replica**, for some reason.

I've registered the following router in the `DATABASE_ROUTERS` settings:

```py
class PrimaryReplicaRouter:
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        return "replica"
```

This should only route *read* operations to the replica, but for some reason, save operations (on models with related models) seem to trigger use of the replica:

```py
In [1]: from django.contrib.auth import User
In [2]: from myapp.models import BlogPost
In [3]: user = User.objects.first()
In [4]: post = BlogPost(user=user)
In [5]: post.save()
# ... <traceback>
OperationalError: (1142, "INSERT command denied to user 'readonly'@'localhost' for table 'myapp_blogpost'")
```

Using `create` on the queryset (e.g. `BlogPost.objects.create(user=user)`), on the other hand, works fine, and so does saving objects that don't have FK references to related models.

This is a simplified version of my models, but the model I'm using only has a reference to the `User` model and some primitive fields and there are no custom `save` methods on the models.

Am I doing something wrong or is this behavior documented somewhere? I haven't been able to find any references to this.

FWIW, this is on Django. 2.2.9 (also tested on 2.2.22) and MySQL 5.7

### Update

After adding `db_for_write` to the router (as [abdul-aziz-barkat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14991864/abdul-aziz-barkat) [suggested to disregard router hints](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67423921/260303)) so that it looks like:

```py
class PrimaryReplicaRouter:
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        return "replica"

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        return "default"
```

I run into the the following error for the related object (probably because the related object was fetched from the replica):

```py
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    481                 # checked) by the RelatedObjectDescriptor.
    482                 if rel_obj is not _DEFERRED:
--> 483                     _setattr(self, field.name, rel_obj)
    484             else:
    485                 if val is not _DEFERRED:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py in __set__(self, instance, value)
    218                 value._state.db = router.db_for_write(value.__class__, instance=instance)
    219             if not router.allow_relation(value, instance):
--> 220                 raise ValueError('Cannot assign "%r": the current database router prevents this relation.' % value)
    221
    222         remote_field = self.field.remote_field

ValueError: Cannot assign "<User: fakeuser>": the current database router prevents this relation.
```

### Second update

[abdul-aziz-barkat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14991864/abdul-aziz-barkat) updated [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67423921/260303) to suggest defining `allow_relation`, which fixes this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your router only defines `db_for_read`. Although I don't know what exactly is happening but I assume, what happens is that `_state.db` of the foreign key is somehow copied to the instance you are creating causing the master router to try saving to `replica`. Another obvious issue you haven't considered is something like this happening:

```
user = User.objects.first()
user.save()
```

In the above snippet the save will be made to `replica` and not the primary database since the model was read from replica and it has `_state.db` set to `replica` and your router has no `db_for_write` so the master router will use the hints for the instance and decide that it needs to save to `replica`. Also since your router has no `allow_relation` method the master db will always assume that objects fetched from different databases cannot have a relation.

The solution is that you need to add a `db_for_write` and a `allow_relation` method to your router:

```
class PrimaryReplicaRouter:
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        return "replica"
    
    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        return "default" # Or whatever database you need to save to
    
    def allow_relation(obj1, obj2, **hints):
        db_list = ["default", 'replica']
        if obj1._state.db in db_list and obj2._state.db in db_list:
            return True
        return False
```

> **Note:** This router is very similar to the one shown in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/multi-db/#an-example) and as stated there it is flawed:
>
> > The primary/replica (referred to as master/slave by some databases)
> > configuration described is also flawed – it doesn’t provide any
> > solution for handling replication lag (i.e., query inconsistencies
> > introduced because of the time taken for a write to propagate to the
> > replicas). It also doesn’t consider the interaction of transactions
> > with the database utilization strategy.

Comment: Thanks! This got around the specific error, but triggered a different error with the same root cause (a model fetched from one db that can't be written to the other). I've updated question description with notes

Comment: @TonySYu you will need a `allow_relation` method too.